# Convert Rows to Columns With Specific Conditions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table in SQL sever 2008 like this

```
ID Name Have
1  Book PageNumber    
2  Book Title
3  Book Papers
4  Car Wheels
5  Car Doors
6  Car Engine
7  Car Windows
```

I want to change the order of column and row like this

```
Name A          B      C       D
Book PageNumber Title  Papers  -
Car  Wheels     Doors  Engine  Windows
```

Is it possible to write a query that automatically make this change?
I have done this in Microsoft Access with Cross Table but in SQL i don't have any idea.

regards,

Comment: I think in need `Rows in Columns` (your title seems to be wrong)

Comment: I agree with you and corrected that issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result by using [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operator:

```
select name
     , [1] as A
     , [2] as B
     , [3] as C
     , [4] as D    
  from ( select name
              , have
              , row_number() over(partition by name order by id) as rn
           from t1
        ) s
 pivot (
   max(have) for rn in ([1], [2],[3], [4])
 ) as pvt
```

Result:

```
NAME    A               B         C         D
------------------------------------------------------------
Book    PageNumber      Title     Papers    (null)
Car     Wheels          Doors     Engine    Windows
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e217/27)

Comment: @nicholasKrasnov  just curious... is anyway to generalize this to variable number of columns without Dynamic SQL?

Comment: @LuisLL Not that I'm aware of.